# Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=5 [WHERE "comments"."post_id" = ?]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cannot delete comments from post. Everything else is working fine. I can create comments but every time I delete I get error message -Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=5 [WHERE "comments"."post_id" = ?] MY code looks good as far as I can tell. I could use some help, please!

## comments_controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)

    flash[:notice] = "Comment was created!"
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    flash[:notice] = "Comment was deleted!"
    redirect_to post_path

  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)   
  end

end
```

### comment.html.erb

```
<div class="comment">

  <p>
    <strong>Comment Name:</strong><br>
      <%= comment.name %> 
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Comment Body:</strong><br>
      <%= comment.body %>
  </p>

  <%= link_to "Delete", [comment.post, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>

</div>
```

### routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get "/pages/about", to: "pages#about", as: :about

  get "pages/contact", to: "pages#contact", as: :contact

  # get "/posts", to: "posts#index"

  # post "/posts", to: "posts#create"

  # get "/post/:id", to: "posts#show", as: :post

  # patch "post/:id", to: "posts#update"

  # delete "post/:id", to: "posts#destroy"

  # get "/posts/new", to: "posts#new", as: :new_post

  # get "/post/:id/edit", to: "posts#edit", as: :edit_post

  resources :posts do 
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end

end
```

### show.html.erb

```
<h1>Show page <%= link_to "Back", posts_path %></h1>

<p>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= @post.body %>
</p>


<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post) %>
<%= link_to "Delete", post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>

<h2>All Comments: </h2>

<%= render @post.comments %>

<h2> Leave a Comment </h2>

<%= form_for [@post, @post.comments.build] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br>

  <%= f.label :body %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :body %><br>

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

### post_controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
     if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Post was successfully created!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if@post.update(post_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Post was updated!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy

    flash[:notice] = "Post was deleted!"
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  private

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end

end
```

Comment: can you show the line where you have mentioned `delete` link for post?

Comment: Can you please add the log with request params

Comment: what is the `comment` value that you are passing in the delete ? `<%= link_to "Delete", [comment.post, comment] %>`

Answer (score 0):

this is your problem

```
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    flash[:notice] = "Comment was deleted!"
    redirect_to post_path

  end
```

`redirect_to post_path` => It will redirect to @post above. You should change to `posts_path`.
Hope this helps.